# How to specify Chrome Device Mode's viewport default value?

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, emulation, viewport

My problem is similar to this one but I'm asking here because no real answer was provided there. ([meta viewport has no effect in Chrome Device Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185620/meta-viewport-has-no-effect-in-chrome-device-mode))

I'm trying to understand how the viewport meta tag affects webpages and I'm just realizing now that Chrome's failure to emulate properly has caused me hours of confusion because my test page renders differently on the device itself.

As I understand it, iOS on a iPhone 5S renders your page as if it were 980px wide by defualt and then zooms out to fit on the small screen. If you have no meta tag to specify the width and initial-scale, the text will be tiny. On my phone, this is exactly what happens and the lines break at 980px, as expected. On Chrome's Device Mode, the font is normal-sized and easily readable and the lines break at around 335px. (Not even at 320px, which is the physical device width??)

How can I fix this? Is it a bug? Is there a setting I can change to make it behave like the physical device? It makes testing for mobile totally useless, doesn't it?

This is the HTML is used to test. (No CSS.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Viewport testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Couldn't figure out how to word wrap the Lorem ipsum text, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

and all the page will fit in the screen (no css).
It's not a bug, just a lack of information for the browser.

Comment: I know that adding that will change how it looks on my phone but that's not the question. Sorry if I wasn't clear. My point is that the same code *should* display the same way on my phone and in Device Mode in Chrome, otherwise what's the point of having "device mode". Either it's a bug or there is a setting in Chrome that I'm unaware of to make it behave just like the physical device does. Or maybe it's something else. Regardless, what do I need to do to make it behave the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is actually emulating the device faithfully. If you run your example on Chrome on Android you'll see that it looks the same as in DevTools' Device Mode. Further, if you check `window.innerWidth` in DevTools you'll see it's ~980 as you'd expect given the lack of a viewport `<meta>` tag.

What you're seeing is another aspect of Chrome Mobile that's being emulated: font boosting. On legacy pages (i.e. pages that don't have a viewport `<meta>` tag) Chrome will boost the size of small text to make it easier to read for users. This makes it seem as if your page is being rendered into a smaller width that it actually is.

Try [disabling font boosting](https://gist.github.com/sethlilly/5880453) or adding an image to your example and it should be clearer that the emulation is working correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't have an Android device. I'm comparing the Chrome Dev Tools Device Mode for "iPhone 5" to my physical iPhone 5S. Shouldn't they render exactly the same? Unless I didn't understand your answer...

Comment: No, Chrome's mobile emulation is still just using the Blink rendering engine to render the page. It can get very close to how the page will look on Chrome on Android since that uses the same engine. Chrome on iOS however, uses the built in iOS WebView which uses WebKit so desktop Chrome can't completely emulate it. It does it's best but these kinds differences will emerge - for the most part, it's just emulating the device dimensions. If it's important to you that your page behave properly on a device you should test on real hardware (particularly for performance characteristics!)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Although, I'm not sure I see the point of having an "emulator" that displays the same code so differently. My reason for wanting to use it was so that I could see how it looks without having to upload and then use my physical phone for every little change. I understand that an emulator wouldn't be exact for every little detail but this seems like a pretty major one to fail on.